# Aptitude puzzle

Tags: algorithm, math, puzzle, catalan

Consider a point P(n,n) in the cartesian co-ordinate system. 
A robot has to start from the origin and reach this point. The only steps
the robot can take are :

- 1 unit right
- 1 unit up.

How many different paths can the robot take to point P?

Is there an optimal path to point P? (Both up and right steps incur the same
cost).

Comment: If right steps and up steps incur the same cost, how could the path cost possibly vary?

Comment: Sounds like an interview question... try recursion for the first part.

Comment: yes its an interview question

Comment: There is a similar problem here: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=15

Answer (score 5):

The total number of paths is

```
(2n choose n)
```

since you must make `n` right steps and `n` up steps to end at the point `(n,n)`, but the order in which you make the steps is irrelevant.

So there are `2n` total steps, of which `n` are right and `n` are up. Choose the positions for the right steps in `(2n choose n)` ways, and the remaining steps must be up steps.

No path is better than any other since all paths use the same number of up and right steps (both `n`).

Answer (score 4):

Scroll [on this Wikipedia article (Catalan number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) until you reach the following picture. The answer is there.

[image: paths]

Thus, total number of paths is

[image: formula]

Note: this forumal is only for monotonic paths, not crossing the diagonal. If you want to allow crossing the diagonal it needs to change a little. Use recursion for that :)

Hope it's useful.

Comment: These are only the paths that stay below the main diagonal.

Comment: There is a note in the response saying that.

Comment: Yes, but I thought a comment was still warranted since this is overkill for this problem. This problem is actually far simpler. Proving that formula for the Catalan numbers is nontrivial. Counting the number of paths the OP seeks is very simple and doesn't require sophisticated arguments.

Comment: (So why the -1? This, well the link really, shows a nice discreet formula.)

Comment: Not sure about the -1, but doing it this way by calculating the Catalan numbers and then adding them up is ridiculous. Counting the paths directly is trivial. This is equivalent to using a sledge hammer to push in a thumb tack.

Comment: I didn't write to add Catalan numbers... The linked article was just an example on how to solve his problem.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be (2n!)/(n!*n!) .

**Explanation :**

You have to reach from origin(0,0) to (n,n) 
Lets say v is the 1 unit vertical up and  h is the 1 unit horizonatally right.
All the paths will look like this - `{vvvhhhvhhhvh.... , vvhhvvhhhvvv...,........)` with v and h spread over a length of number of v's + number of h's and that has to be the

> n + n = 2n.

Now total number of paths will be the combiantion of vs and hs in 2n places 
That will be equal to

> (n+n)!/(n!*n!)

since v and h are repeated.
Had there been some other unit like a or b it would have been considered in that as well.
I think it will not be a **catalan number** as pointed .
Rgds,
Softy